# Iterating over symbol table in Trace32 PRACTICE script

Tags: debugging, arm, embedded, trace32, lauterbach

I want to iterate over a symbol table database created by the trace32 debugger and want to execute a specific command on the iterator (which I expect to be a name of the symbol).
Currently I am exporting the list of all symbols to a text file and using a python script to create a .cmm file which execute the required commands on each symbol parsed from the text file I created (Python script generates a big cmm file which have multiple copies of the set of trace32 commands, the only change is the symbol name)

Is there any better way to iterate over the symbol table to get all the symbol names.

I tried using

```
sYmbol.ForEach "<cmd>" [<name_pattern> [<type_pattern>]]
```

command but did not find a way to pass a symbol as a input to my command.
my commadn is -> ECHO sYmbol.BEGIN()

Answer (score 1):

Use the asterisk to define where in `<cmd>` you want to insert the symbol name:

```
sYmbol.ForEach "ECHO sYmbol.BEGIN(*)" [<name_pattern> [<type_pattern>]]
```